# WordPress - Adding widgets programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress

I asked this question at wordpress.stackexchange.com but no reply.

I want to add widgets to my wordpress site programmatically. I tried the following code from the [codex docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_widget):

```
class MyNewWidget extends WP_Widget {

    function MyNewWidget() {
        // Instantiate the parent object
        parent::__construct( false, 'My New Widget Title' );
    }

    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        // Widget output
    }

    function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        // Save widget options
    }

    function form( $instance ) {
        // Output admin widget options form
    }
}

function myplugin_register_widgets() {
    register_widget( 'MyNewWidget' );
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'myplugin_register_widgets' );
```

But doesn't seem to work. I even tried the code from the question [Programmatically add widgets to sidebars](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26557/programmatically-add-widgets-to-sidebars) but to no avail. Please tell me if I am missing out something.

Thankyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have the constructor wrong. Try the following:

```
<?php

add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("MyNewWidget");') );

class MyNewWidget extends WP_Widget {
    function __construct() {
        $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'MyNewWidget', 'description' => __('Widget description'));
        parent::__construct('MyNewWidget', __('Widget Name'), $widget_ops);
    }

    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract($args);
        echo $before_widget;

        echo $before_title . __('Widget title') . $after_title;

        // widget logic/output

        echo $after_widget;
    }

    function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        // Save widget options
    }

    function form( $instance ) {
        // Output admin widget options form
    }
}

?>
```

Also make sure you have a description and all for this to make it a plugin, and activate it in the admin panel under plugins.